# freopen not writing to the specified file

Tags: c++, linux, stdout, stderr, freopen

I am trying to redirect output of stdout and stderr using a file. I am using freopen and it creates the file in the correct directory but the file is blank. When I comment out the code to redirect the stdout and stderr - the output shows up on the console.

Here is the code:

```
freopen(stderrStr.c_str(), "a+", stderr); //where stderrStr and stdoutStr are the path/file name
freopen(stdoutStr.c_str(), "a+", stdout);

fclose(stdout); 
fclose(stderr);
```

I have placed a printf("I WORK") in main and without the the suppressant it outputs but wont write to the file.

Comment: Never close stdout or stderr, it gets closed automatically at the program end.

Comment: @dark_charlie I got the example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/

and I commented out those close statements and it didnt work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do what you are trying to do I use **dup2(2)**.

Simply **open(2)** two files fd1 and fd2 and then use `dup2(fd1, 1)` for stdout and `dup2(fd2, 2)` for stderr.

The OS (libc, loader or kernel, not sure which) sets up 3 open file descriptors before the entry of main:

```
0 : stdin pipe
1 : stdout pipe
2 : stderr pipe
```

and from the docs of dup2:

> dup2(int oldfd, int newfd) makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary

so the two dup2 calls replace 1 and 2 with your open files.  So after when your process calls **write(2)** (the syscall all output routines such as printf and cout call) to fd 1 or fd 2 the data will be written to your files rather than to the pipes setup by the OS

**man page note**:

man pages come in chapters. the notation **foo(N)** means the man page of name "foo" in chapter N.  To open foo(N) type:

```
$ man N foo
```

for example to open write(2) type:

```
$ man 2 write
```