# Function freopen() does not write in file

Tags: c++, freopen

I have next simple code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fout;
  fout = freopen("stdout.txt", "w", stdout);

  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("print('Message')"); 
  Py_Finalize();

  fclose(fout);
  return 0;
}
```

I supposed that output file "stdout.txt" must contain printed message, but it is empty. Trying to read about function `freopen()`, but everywhere I see similar example. Also I read this question:
[freopen not writing to the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914907/freopen-not-writing-to-the-specified-file)
but can't understand what that solution's author means and how realize this solution in code..

Comment: Did you check that `fout` is not NULL?  Does the message appear anywhere, or is it lost?

Comment: Is it compiling?  I guess you should replace PyRun_SimpleString("print("Message")");   with PyRun_SimpleString("print(\"Message\")");

Comment: 1) Yes I check, fout is not NULL.
2) message is lost, it dont print in console and dont write in file.

Comment: im sorry, this is my mistake, should replace print("Message") on print('Message')

Comment: Any chance that you are using Windows? Which, from what I remember, doesn't work right for `freopen` on `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Yes, i using Windows. Guess it is a problem. And with stderr it not work too...

Comment: @Corban_Dallas Maybe a platform-specific problem. Tested on Linux 3.12.9 x86_64 with Python 3.3.4 and GCC 4.8.2, and it works as expected.